# Scraping active users from Telegram chats instead of all users

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I wish to scrape a Telegram groups userlist by using the Telethon API.
Thereby it scrapes all users in the group and i want to only scrape the ACTIVE ones from the past 24 hours / recently.
Yet i am unable to do so / don't understand.
Would be very nice if someone could help me out and show me where to place the intended code

Thanks in regards !

````
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import csv

api_id = 
api_hash = ''
phone = '+'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))


chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])      
print('Members scraped successfully.')```
````

Answer (score 5):

You can use user.status get the users online status.
If user is offline. There you can get was_online time.
[Check this](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/user_status.html)

you can then calculate if it is greater than a certain time period. 
Then you can start working the member scraping. Full code should be updated to

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, InputPeerChannel, InputPeerUser
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError, UserPrivacyRestrictedError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
import sys
import csv
import traceback
import time
from datetime import datetime
api_id = 
api_hash = ''
phone = ''
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code recieved to your Telegram messenger: '))


chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id','last seen'])
    for user in all_participants:
        accept=True
        try:
            lastDate=user.status.was_online
            num_months = (datetime.now().year - lastDate.year) * 12 + (datetime.now().month - lastDate.month)
            if(num_months>1):
                accept=False
        except:
            continue

        if (accept) :
            if user.username:
                username= user.username
            else:
                username= ""
            if user.first_name:
                first_name= user.first_name
            else:
                first_name= ""
            if user.last_name:
                last_name= user.last_name
            else:
                last_name= ""
            name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
            writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id,user.status]) 

print('Members scraped successfully.')
```

Comment: Hi , would to check what was intepret  " num_months>1 " ? mean user not active more than 1 month will not be scrape ?

Comment: Yes. In this way you could get only the active users